# Controller not recognized by pygame and DS4Windows after turning off and on Bluetooth

Tags: python, pygame

I am facing an issue with my controller in both pygame and DS4Windows. Initially, everything was working fine, but after I turned off my Bluetooth and then turned it back on, the controller is no longer recognized by either pygame or DS4Windows.

I am using the following code in Python with pygame to interface with the controller:

```
import pygame
import vgamepad as vg
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()
gamepad = vg.VDS4Gamepad()
joystick = None

while True:
    while pygame.joystick.get_count() == 0:
        sleep(1)

    # Check if the joystick is disconnected
    if joystick is not None and not joystick.get_init():
        joystick = None

    if joystick is None:
        joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
        joystick.init()

    pygame.event.get()

    # Check if the joystick is still valid before accessing its properties
    if joystick is not None and joystick.get_init():
        buttons = [joystick.get_button(i) for i in range(joystick.get_numbuttons())]
        axes = [joystick.get_axis(i) for i in range(joystick.get_numaxes())]
        
        print("Buttons:", buttons)
        print("Axes:", axes)

        for k, j in enumerate(buttons):
            if j:
                gamepad.press_button(vg.XUSB_BUTTON(k))
            else:
                gamepad.release_button(vg.XUSB_BUTTON(k))

        gamepad.left_joystick(x_value=int(joystick.get_axis(0) * 32767), y_value=int(joystick.get_axis(1) * 32767))
        gamepad.right_joystick(x_value=int(joystick.get_axis(2) * 32767), y_value=int(joystick.get_axis(3) * 32767))
        gamepad.left_trigger(int(joystick.get_axis(4) * 32767))
        gamepad.right_trigger(int(joystick.get_axis(5) * 32767))

        gamepad.update()

    sleep(0.005)
```

Comment: This is a problem with your system (hardware or software), but not with your code.

Comment: Do you have any advises?

Comment: Actually, no. But you are in the wrong place here. The purpose of this site is to answer questions about code, not to solve hardware or system problems.